# Cordova project in eclipse error

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

This is the exact command I run in the CLi:

1. ionic start myApp tabs
2. cd myApp
3. ionic platform add android
4. ionic run android

I use an android device as emulator, it run properly in the phone.

I try to open that project using eclipse, it got these errors :
[image]

Comment: did you add the cordovaLib project too?

Comment: @jcesarmobile I think that is missing, where to get that?

Comment: when you import the android folder, it should show 2 projects, one for the actual project and another for the cordovaLib project

Comment: @jcesarmobile Yes I have both checked and imported both.